# How to write a c# custom class for sdo_geometry an oracle udt using odp.net managed client

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm stuck on as how to write a custom c# class in order to fetch and update/insert values for a field of type  sdo_geometry (which is a user defined type for oracle and a custom type for .net) along with other fields which are non utd, from oracle database.

I googled a lot and ended up getting a custom code written with the help of types used from inside Oracle.DataAccess.dll(odp.net unmanaged driver).

Though I have been instructed to write the same custom code using odp.net's managed version(with  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) and when I looked in this dll I couldn't find some classes and interfaces which were defined in Oracle.DataAccess.dll so I was not in a position to take advantage of the ready made code and also I have been told that it's easy to deploy code written with odp.net managed driver compared  odp.net unmanaged driver.

Even I tried using the custom class code generator from inside visual studio but it doesn't give me any c# custom class rather it gets stuck on its way to completion and throws an error.

Any suggestion on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you need: https://github.com/mapspiral/NetSdoGeometry/ ? I am currently using that package to retrieve SDO_GEOMETRY from oracle 11.2 and map it to "the .net-domain", works like a charm.

Comment: This Package uses the unmanaged Driver (Oracle.DataAccess). The Managed Driver (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) does still not support User Defined Types. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use UDTs with the managed driver at this time per this post from the Oracle Product development team.  However, you may have success serializing it without the UDT via wrapper functions/procs/packages.

[Migration Guide for ODP.NET Managed Driver Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (from Unmanaged Driver - Oracle.DataAccess)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3540995)

> Alex_Keh - Oracle_Product_Manager  Mar 31, 2014 11:11 AM  (in response
>   to kiquenet)
>
> UDTs and VARRAYs are not supported by managed ODP.NET yet.
>
> For supported features, migration should be as simple as changing the
>   namespace references and changes to how the managed ODP.NET finds the
>   *.ora configuration files.

Comment: Yes I figured it out earlier on, thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Oracle made it possible to use their managed drivers having UDT's. I've made a modified version of NetSdoGeometry and put it on Github.

https://github.com/flappah/ManagedNetSdoGeometry

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32934178)